# Batch File SQL Plus ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error for particular connection

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I have created a batch file for executing multiple .sql files in folder in oracle.
connection in batch is as : SQLPLUS -s %u%/%pass%@%h% @  %%X >> %logfilepath%
where u is username, p is password and h is the tns tag from tnsnames.ora file.I have two oracle connection.However SQLPlus connection only works for one connection and not for the other. SQL tools is connecting both the connection.Please advise the possible solution for this.

Comment: Try to connect to the DB without using a TNSNAMES.ORA alias. Simplest way is to "SET h=%server%:%port%/%sid%"
If this is working then you have error in your TNSNAMES.ORA. Be advised that SQL TOOLS can connect to the database bypassing TNSNAMES.ORA

Comment: @MiroslavDuník I tried connecting as you have mentioned but this doesn't work as well and gives the same error.My concern is that how come SQl tools is reading the connection details from tns file and my batch file cant for that particular connection, whereas for other connection it is going all fine.I cross checked the TNS file and it seems all okay.

Comment: @MiroslavDuník FYI SQL tools has not bypassed the TNSNAMES.ORA and getting the connection details from TNSNAMES.ORA file.

Comment: I resolved this issue myself. everything in batch file was correct and the sql plus connection too. It was just because of the ! inbetween the password characters of that particular database. which i resolved by inserting ^^! insetead of ! in the password.Thank you everyone!